# What they mean when they say "Off season April's fool joke"?

Tags: word-meaning

Do they mean "An *annoying* prank that maybe okay in April's fool, but not right now."

Or do they mean "A prank that's more fitting to be done in April's fool, but it's *welcomed* nonetheless."

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to provide some more context? What's happening? Was there dialogue?

Comment: Actually, I accidentally saw this on Google search result, but I have read this sentence many times in the past, but never think about it until right now. But I see now that to determine the answer to my question, one actually need more context about the whole full sentences, not just this phrase, which can mean differently on different context.

Comment: Can you find an example and include it here? I think it would be helpful.

Comment: The sentence says *nothing at all* about the joke being welcomed or appropriate or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Off season April's fool joke" is not a commonly used expression; therefore, you need to deduce whether the joke was welcome or not from the context. I believe the intent was to indicate that the joke was the kind of joke that would be done on the 1st of April (which does not necessarily mean even then that it would be welcome).

Off-season is an expression which just refers to a particular time of year when a particular activity is less commonly (or never) performed and the place hosting the activity is not busy. Typically, it refers to holidays, sporting or leisure activities. For example, February would be "off season" at a European seaside resort.

Answer (score 1):

An "off-season" event is simply one that is performed outside of its usual season.    For example, a Christmas party in May would be considered "off-season".  It normally refers to sports or popular holidays, but in theory could apply to anything with a season.

April Fool's Day (April 1st) is traditionally a day for playing pranks.  An *off-season* April Fool's prank (or joke), therefore, is one that was *not* performed on April 1st.